# wordpress-page-titles

Tags: custom-wordpress-pages

I just want to ask how to put my wordpress page title in 2 lines with the a break and centered. It should be like this:

```
                     Arthritis Pain & Treatment
by NUCCA Chiropractor, Dr. Devin Luzod & Spinal Care of Nevada Las Vegas
```

I write my page title like this:

> ```
> Arthritis Pain & Treatment <br><font size="+2">by NUCCA Chiropractor, Dr. Devin Luzod & >     Spinal Care of Nevada Las Vegas</font>
> ```

I got the exact result I wanted but I'm having a strange line right in between of every page. That is:

> ```
> by%20NUCCA%20Chiropractor,%20Dr.%20Devin%20Luzod%20&%20Spinal%20Care%20of%20Nevada%20Las%20Vegas')}else{var%20b=a2a_config.localize.BookmarkInstructions%20||%20'Press%20Ctrl+D%20to%20bookmark%20this%20page';alert(a2a_config.localize.BookmarkInstructions)}" title="Bookmark/Favorites" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
> ```

I don't know how to remove it.

Comment: What is the  `& >` in your code? Did you check that you closed the tags correctly?

Comment: yup i do.but this is not the professional way to get the output i want as placing code in page titles.please guide me the correct way so that the client as well can insert page title with the same output.

Comment: Please, edit your post and put all the code relevant to the title, even with the tags. With that, we could see better if there is a tag mistake of another kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

Add a comma in title and now please find below the solution.

```
 <?php echo str_replace(',','<br />',get_the_title()); ?>
```

Replace comma with break  in the title.